# Unable to Upload Image Loaded in ImageView to Firebase

Tags: android, android-camera, firebase-storage

I have successfully opened the Camera, clicked the Image and Shown in InageView, but when i click on Upload Image Button, the "ELSE" condition is executing instead of "if" condition

Here is my Activity Code :

```
chooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }

        }
    });

btnUploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                uploadImage();
            }
        }
    });


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
             imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            imgUrl = data.getData();

        }
    }
```

Here is my UploadImage method :

```
 private void uploadImage() {
        if (imgUrl != null) {
            final StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + "jpg");

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imgUrl)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    uploadProgress.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 500);


                            fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Upload upload = new Upload( uri.toString());
                                    String uploadID = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                                    mDatabaseRef.child(uploadID).setValue(upload);
                                    Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "Upload successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    imgPreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagepreview);
//                                    imgDescription.setText("");
                                }
                            });


                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            uploadProgress.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Here is my layout XML code :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtUploadImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagepreview" />

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/chooseImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/uploadProgress"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_camera"
        android:text="Chooese Image from camera"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUploadImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_upload"
        android:text="Upload Image"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

The "else" condition in UploadImage method is executing everyTime (No File Selected) , how to successfully get the URI and Upload the Image ??

Comment: Log `imgUrl` on Button click and check if value is available or not

Comment: i have uploaded image, but now problem is Image is of Very Low Quality, how to fix this ??

Comment: [This guide](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) covers the whole flow of taking photo.

Answer (score 0):

```
 btnUploadImage.setOnClickListener(new.     
 View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mUploadTask != null && 
  mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                 Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "Upload in.       
   progress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } else {
                 uploadImage();
             }
         }
});
```

In the above code, you r checking in your if condition
whether mUploadTask is not null then execute....
This is the reason why the else is getting executed
because mUploadTask is still empty i.e. null when you
click on the upload button.

Comment: So, how can I pass ImageUri in putFile() from image which is already loaded in ImageView